# Search an array based on search text using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dictionary, filter

I am a newbie to swift and i have a new project. I am trying to do a search feature. I have a array of dictionaries, containing firstName and lastName as keys, i need to filter out people based on the firstName which contains the search string

```
let nameList : [Dictionary<String,String>] = 
[["firstName" : "John Sam","lastName" : "Smith"],
["firstName" : "Johnny","lastName" : "Smith"],
["firstName" : "Albert","lastName" : "Smith"],
["firstName" : "Alby","lastName" : "Wright"],
["firstName" : "Smith","lastName" : "Green"]]
```

As in objective C i could easily do with

```
[NSPredicate predicatewithformat:"firstName contains[c] %@",searchText]
```

I also understand that the same predicate can be done on Swift .but i am looking for an equivalent Swift, so that i can gain how to use map and filter. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A search corresponding to the predicate operator `"CONTAINS[c]"` can be achieved with `rangeOfString()` with the `.CaseInsensitiveSearch` option:

```
let searchText = "MITH"

let filtered = nameList.filter {
    return $0["firstName"]?.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
}

// Result: [[firstName: Smith, lastName: Green]]
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let filtered = nameList.filter {
    return $0["firstName"]?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter by defining a function to filter by first, or just include the filter in a closure.  Here's an excerpt that you can paste into a playground that demonstrates both options:

```
let nameList : [Dictionary<String,String>] =
[["firstName" : "John Sam","lastName" : "Smith"],
    ["firstName" : "Johnny","lastName" : "Smith"],
    ["firstName" : "Albert","lastName" : "Smith"],
    ["firstName" : "Alby","lastName" : "Wright"],
    ["firstName" : "Smith","lastName" : "Green"]]

func fn (x: Dictionary<String,String>) -> Bool {
    return x["firstName"] == "Johnny"
}

nameList.filter(fn)

var r = nameList.filter({$0["firstName"] == "Johnny"})

r

var s = nameList.filter({$0["lastName"] == "Smith"})

s
```

You can also filter the results of a filter to search for first and last name, e.g.

```
var result = (nameList.filter({$0["lastName"] == "Smith"})).filter({$0["firstName"] == "Johnny"})
```

See also: http://locomoviles.com/ios-tutorials/filtering-swift-array-dictionaries-object-property/

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following way.

I have passed `constant value` you need to pass your `dynamic value` at place of `someString variable`.

```
let someString = "Alby"
        var arr:NSArray =
            [["firstName" : "John Sam","lastName" : "Smith"],
            ["firstName" : "Johnny","lastName" : "Smith"],
            ["firstName" : "Albert","lastName" : "Smith"],
            ["firstName" : "Alby","lastName" : "Wright"],
            ["firstName" : "Smith","lastName" : "Green"]]


        var pre:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName CONTAINS[c] %@", someString)!
        var result:NSArray = arr.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(pre)

        print(result)
```

Comment: I already said i know how to use NSPredicate with Swift. I am looking for swift filter

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
let searchText = "John Sam"

func isMatch (nameDictionary: Dictionary<String, String>) -> Bool {
    if(nameDictionary["firstName"] == searchText) {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }

}

let results = nameList.filter(isMatch)
```

You are free to use closure.

```
let searchText = "John Sam"

let results = nameList.filter {
    nameDictionary in
    nameDictionary["firstName"] == searchText
}
```

or,

```
let searchText = "John Sam"
    let results = nameList.filter {
        $0["firstName"] == searchText
    }
```